# cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked - Is blocking my React and ReactDOM script tags in my HTML document

Tags: reactjs

I'm taking a course on React and while doing a very simple exercise to simply render a react component to the DOM, I keep getting a CORB error while trying to import the React and ReactDOM library through a script tag.

```
<body>
    <div id="root">React is NOT rendered</div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/browse/react@18.0.0-rc.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18.0.0-rc.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script>
      const App = () => {
        return React.createElement("div", {}, [
          React.createElement("h1", { class: "title" }, "React IS rendered"),
        ]);
      };

      ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(App, document.getElementById("root"))
      );
    </script>
  </body>
```

I just tried to render an h1 with the following "React IS rendered" text. I'm not sure what to do to fix this issue.

Comment: It seem like you need to pass the [`crossorigin`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html) attribute to your `script` tags that import the package

Comment: I tried it but it would still return an error :/